# ¿Cómo valido si una variable contiene un número?

Tags: php

¿Cómo puedo hacer que se cumpla un "if" solo si mi variable es un numero?

```
$minumero = $_POST["numero"];

if (is_numeric == $minumero){
     //hace acción 1 
} else {
     //hace acción 2 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Estás usando mal la función `is_numeric()`. Tienes que pasarle el valor en parámetro, por ejemplo:

```
 #Conviene también verificar el POST para evitar Undefined index
 #aquí usaremos un ternario
 $minumero = isset($_POST["numero"]) ?  $_POST["numero"] : NULL;
 if ( is_numeric($minumero) ){
     //hace acción 1 
 }else{
     //hace acción 2 
 }
```

Te recuerdo el tipo de evaluación que hace `is_numeric()`, según el [Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.is-numeric.php):

> **Comprueba si una variable es un número o un string numérico.**
>
> Comprueba si la variable dada es numérica. Los string numéricos
> consisten en un signo opcional, cualquier número de dígitos, una parte
> decimal opcional y una parte exponencial opcional. En consecuencia,
> `+0123.45e6` es un valor numérico válido. Las notaciones hexadecimal
> (p.ej. `0xf4c3b00c`) y binary (p.ej. `0b10100111001`) están permitidas
> pero únicamente sin signo, parte decimal y exponencial.